# Jetpack Compose with WindowManager - Cannot start this animator on a detached view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-service, android-view, android-windowmanager

I am currently working on an Android library called [Floating-Bubble-View](https://github.com/TorryDo/Floating-Bubble-View), this library helps create a floating view on the screen. Recently, I added support for `Composable` and with the help of a custom `LifecycleOwner`, I can show/remove the composable without any issue. However, when scrolling through the LazyColumn, if I call `removeView` before the animation stops, the app start crashing. this is the error message:

```
Process: com.torrydo.testfloatingbubble, PID: 29264
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!
at android.graphics.RenderNode.addAnimator(RenderNode.java:1469)
at android.graphics.animation.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:288)
at android.graphics.animation.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:277)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleForeground.startPending(RippleForeground.java:139)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleForeground.drawHardware(RippleForeground.java:168)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleForeground.draw(RippleForeground.java:340)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.drawBackgroundAndRipples(RippleDrawable.java:848)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.draw(RippleDrawable.java:679)
at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:22581)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22342)
at androidx.compose.material.ripple.AndroidRippleIndicationInstance.drawIndication(Ripple.android.kt:204)
```

and this is remove function

```kotlin
fun remove() {
     builder.composeView?.also { composeView ->
        builder.composeLifecycleOwner?.onPause()
        builder.composeLifecycleOwner?.onStop()
        windowManager!!.removeView(composeView)
     }
}
```

basic composable with a button to pop back to the screen, and a `LazyColumn`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from **Lan Lake**, currently an Android SE at Google. I realized that I wasn't calling `onDestroy()` when removing the `ComposeView`. As a result, the `composable` wasn't triggering the `disposal`. Here's the updated code snippet.

```kotlin
builder.composeView?.also {
       builder.composeLifecycleOwner?.onPause()
       builder.composeLifecycleOwner?.onStop()
       builder.composeLifecycleOwner?.onDestroy() // added
       super.remove(it)
}
```